# USB driver: usb_register function does not return or behave as expected

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, driver

I am trying to write a driver for a PS4 joystick just to learn.
I have a problem with the usb_register function.

Looking at the documentation this function should return a negative code in case of error or 0  otherwise.

My code looks like:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>

#define USB_VENDOR_ID 0x054c
#define USB_PRODUCT_ID 0x09cc

static int ps4controller_probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id);
static inline void ps4controller_disconnect(struct usb_interface *dev);

static struct usb_device_id ps4controller_table [] = {
        { USB_DEVICE(USB_VENDOR_ID, USB_PRODUCT_ID) },
        { }                      /* Terminating entry */
};

static struct usb_driver ps4controller_driver = {
        .name        = "ps4controller",
        .probe       = ps4controller_probe,
        .disconnect  = ps4controller_disconnect,
        .id_table    = ps4controller_table,
};


MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE (usb, ps4controller_table);

static int ps4controller_probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "ps4 controller plugged");
    return 0;
}

static inline void ps4controller_disconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
 printk(KERN_INFO "ps4 controller disconnected");
 return;
}

static int __init usb_ps4controller_init(void)
{
        int res;

        printk(KERN_INFO "ps4 controller initialising");

        res = usb_register(&ps4controller_driver);
        if (res < 0) {
                printk(KERN_INFO "usb_register failed with error %d", res);
        } else {
                printk(KERN_INFO "ps4 initialised");
        }

        return res;

}

static void __exit usb_ps4controller_exit(void)
{
        /* deregister this driver with the USB subsystem */
        usb_deregister(&ps4controller_driver);
}

module_init(usb_ps4controller_init);
module_exit(usb_ps4controller_exit);


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("melix");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A PS4 Driver");
```

I am just playing with the probe function. I would expect the message

```
ps4 controller plugged
```

printed each time i plug the joystick in.

When a install the module with:

```
sudo insmod ps4controller.ko
```

The output on dmesg is:

```
[ 1565.246973] ps4 controller initializing
[ 1565.247014] usbcore: registered new interface driver ps4controller
```

I was expecting to see in output also:

`usb_register failed with error %d`

or

```
ps4 initialized
```

when i remove the module with:

```
sudo rmmod ps4controller.ko
```

on dmesg is printed:

```
[ 1775.931354] ps4 initialized
[ 1778.719571] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ps4controller
```

I do not have an idea of what is going on here since I do not have experience with Kernel code.

I also disable the existing driver via udev with the following role:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="054c", ATTR{idProduct}=="09cc", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"
```

My kernel version is:
5.4.0-58-generic

**[UPDATE I]**

I had to add a \n at the end of each printk as Hasturkun kindly suggested.

Now, I see the expected messages when a install the module:

```
[ 6723.508756] ps4 controller initialising 
[ 6723.508800] usbcore: registered new interface driver ps4controller
[ 6723.508801] ps4 initialised 0
```

However the prob function is not called, neither if I unplug and plug the joystick.

Indeed, if I unplug and plug the joystick again I see:

```
[ 6850.142938] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 17
[ 6860.737866] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 6860.908617] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=09cc, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 6860.908622] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6860.908625] usb 1-3: Product: Wireless Controller
[ 6860.908627] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Sony Interactive Entertainment
[ 6861.042258] input: Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0011/input/input58
[ 6861.042508] input: Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller Motion Sensors as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0011/input/input59
[ 6861.101998] input: Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0011/input/input57
[ 6861.102278] sony 0003:054C:09CC.0011: input,hidraw0: USB HID v81.11 Gamepad [Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller] on usb-0000:05:00.3-3/input3
```

but not the printk message I have in my probe function.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but your `printk` formats should probably end with `\n`.

Comment: \o/ that solved the problem! thanks a lot. Now, I have to figure it out why the probe function is not called.

Comment: I have a very similar set of code and also am not getting my probe function called.  Did you ever sort out why? thanks!